# JPA - one parent table and multiple optional field table based on category

Tags: jpa

I'm using JPA and Hibernate framework. In that the existing table has one parent table and multiple optional table based on category. I want to do two things,

1. when I save the parent entity the sub optional field which is not null should save
2. When I fetch by parent table by id all the optional field table should fetch.

Let's say, we've requirement that common fields and optional filed for each category. every thing is one-to-one. we decided to create master table for common fields and split each sub field for each category into separate table.

But our problem is how to give relationship with all sub field in the master table?

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="master")
public class Master {
@Id
private int id; //auto generated
@column(name = "name")
private String name;
private Category1;// doesn't have column in the master table
private Category2;//doesn't have column in the master table
}
public class Category1 {
@Id
private int id; //auto generated
private optionalField1;
private optioalField2;

@column(name = "master_id")
private int masterId //master table foreign key
}

public class Category2 {
@Id
private int id; //auto generated

private optionalField3;
private optioalField4;

@column(name = "master_id")
private int masterId //master table foreign key
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### [@OneToOne](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToOne)

You can use a @OneToOne relationship on the child and parent fields with an @JoinColumn on the Child to show they own the relationship. It would look something like this:

```
@Entity @Table(name ="PARENT")
public class Parent{
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="parent")
    private Child child1;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="parent")
    private Child child2;
}

@Entity @Table(name ="CHILD")
public class Child {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @OneToOne @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID")
    private Parent parent;
}
```

Note: The "cascade=CascadeType.ALL" added to the @OneToOne relationship means that, when persisting entities of type **Parent**, the **Child** entity will also be persisted!

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention the entity annotation in both category1 and category2 since these two were persistent entity. Here in my example the child has parent_id but parent don't have child_id. I didn't try your solution @JoinColumn(cascade="child_id") rather I tried @JoinColumn(name="", referenceTableName=""). Let you know If this work's and thanks for giving this key idea!!!

Comment: @SathishThangathurai Oh, that was a copy/paste mistake. I did not mean @JoinColumn(cascade="child_id"), but rather @JoinColumn(**name**="child_id"). I will update to fix that.

Comment: The important part of the solution is `@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)`. By having the cascade set on the relationship to ALL, when persisting an entity of type Parent, this will cascade that persist to the entities in it's relationship. So Child will be persisted as well. `@JoinColumn` is how you tell JPA which entity OWNS the relationship (gets a ForeignKey) and is used in conjunction with `@OneToOne`

Comment: Ok, I just realized you were looking for the Child to own the relationship. I have updated my answer to reflect this. Also, I removed the @Embeddable after you said you were looking for the Children to be entities.